# processing 2.0 not executing any sketches. It works fine in Javascript mode, but not in java

Tags: sublimetext2, processing

Im an absolute beginner here and I just signed up for some tutorials in generative visualisation using sublime text-2 for processing. 
Im using Processing 2.0 right now and the thing is that none of the sketches in processing(even the examples) run when i hit cmd-r. The run button turns yellow but nothing happens. But when I change the mode to 'java script' the sketch opens up and displays in my browser.
What am I doing wrong here? Can someone please help me?

Comment: Have you tried updating to the latest version of Processing? Have you tried running directly from the Processing editor instead of going through sublime text?

Comment: @KevinWorkman Thanks for the reply Kevin! I have tried running it directly from Processing and I have the same issue.

Comment: I installed the latest version of processing ver 3.05b and now I have the added problem of not being able to instal java script mode since i get a message saying this mode is not compatible with this version.
I'm totally lost and I could really use some step by step assistance

Answer (score 0):

I did a bit of research and found out that it is indeed an issue found within the Processing 2.0 application (source: https://github.com/processing/processing/issues/1817)

In terms of solving it, I did say within the issue to install the latest version of Processing here: https://processing.org/download/, the latest is 3.3.7, when I ran a sketch using Processing 3.3.7, it did work.

My answer appears via the exact link to the issue: https://github.com/processing/processing/issues/1817.

I hope that this solves your problem.